# How to change the values of a DocumentTermMatrix matrix?

Tags: r, tm, topic-modeling

Repex:

Suppose I have the dtm:

```
library(topicmodels)
data(AssociatedPress)
```

I am trying to assign a value of `.001` to all those values that are `0`

Use case:

I get this error when I run LDA on my matrix

> Error in LDA(notSparse, k, method = "Gibbs", control = list(nstart =
>   nstart,  :    Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least
>   one non-zero entry

I would like to see what happens if I turn the zeros into small values to reduce sparsity instead of using the dedicated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your matrix values from 0 to 0.001 will not work with `topicmodels::LDA`. 
There is a check in the code that expects all values to be integer values. Which means values of 0.001 are not allowed. See example below:

```
m_replaced_zero <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0.001, 0), nrow = 2)
LDA(m_replaced_zero)
Error in !all.equal(x$v, as.integer(x$v)) : invalid argument type
```

Weirdly the error you get means that you have a row in your matrix that only contains 0. Which shouldn't happen unless you removed some terms from your documenttermmatrix which resulted in a row where there is no value of 1 or more. See example below.

```
m_zero_row <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 0), nrow = 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    0
LDA(m_zero_row)
Error in LDA(m_zero_row) : 
  Each row of the input matrix needs to contain at least one non-zero entry
```

But if you are set on replacing the sparse entries in a documenttermmatrix, you first need to transform it into a matrix and then replace the 0's.

```
data("AssociatedPress")
m <- as.matrix(AssociatedPress)
m[m==0] <- 0.001
```